# Distortion at edges of planetscope images

Tags: aerial-photography, planet

Does anyone know why there is distortion on the edges of some planetscope images?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is an effect you can see on older Planet imagery known as [vignetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting). Fortunately, this only affected older sensors with the classification of PS0 and PS1, whereas all newer satellites (roughly mid-2015 onwards) are PS2.

You can filter for newer satellite imagery only by using API filters on the `instrument` field in the metadata, looking for the `PS2` designation.

Here's an example of PS2 metadata: https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item-types/PSScene3Band/items/20160828_172140_0e30.

Comment: I would add that the _udm.tif files for PS0 and PS1 analytic scenes include masking for the corner areas.  The visual products have an alpha band representing this distinction (transparent in the corners) which gives a visually unique rounded effect.  The issues in the image corners are because the telescope is essentially imaging the sides of the telescope tube in the corners.